# How to use script tags inside .hbs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, hbs

I am going crazy about this issue. I am trying to assign a js function to a input-field on a .hbs file adding on the same file a tag script where I have written the event function. Please, someone could give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: What does your handlebars template have to do with the problem? That's just a way to dynamically generate HTML (or other things). The browser only sees the HTML document. How you add an event listener is fairly trivial JS (plus the HTML to create the elements). We can't see what you are doing wrong without a [mcve]. Please read [ask]. (And not the *minimal* part; you probably don't need to include any handlebars code at all).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.